# how to turn projectID: ModuleID (for a Project) into the ModuleID in the UpdateReport

Tags: sbt

If one requests the `projectID` for a `Project`, it is returned without (at least) the scala cross version. i.e. the bits that appear in the `toString` look like `org.ensime:util:0.9.10-SNAPSHOT`.

What I need from this is the exact `ModuleID` for this `Project`, such as it appears in the `UpdateReport`, which typically looks like this `org.ensime:util_2.11:0.9.10-SNAPSHOT`.

Anyone know how to do that without just hacking the `String`s?

Also, in the `UpdateReport`, I'm able to build up a `Map[(ModuleID, Configuration), Seq[ModuleID]]` but I really need `Map[(ModuleID, Configuration), Seq[(ModuleID, Configuration)]]` (i.e. include the dependent's configuration, not just the dependee's)

*I can hear the tumbleweed already*

Answer (score 1):

Johannes Rudolph pointed out that in https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph/blob/master/src/main/scala/net/virtualvoid/sbt/graph/DependencyGraphSettings.scala#L44 they construct the `ModuleID` like this:

```
CrossVersion(scalaVersion.gimme, scalaBinaryVersion.gimme)(projectID.gimme)
```

This constructs the correct `toString` but it doesn't `equals` the versions in `UpdateReport`.

Also, I still don't know how to get the `Configuration` for the targets.